# ORDER BY VS GROUP BY COUNT(*)

Tags: group-by, count, sql-order-by, aggregation

question:
why am I not able to *GROUP BY num_accounts* in:

```
select c.cust_id, COUNT(*) num_accounts
from customer c LEFT JOIN
account a on a.account_id = c.cust_id
GROUP BY c.cust_id, num_accounts;
```

Instead I have to put '*num_accounts*' into *ORDER BY* clause:

```
select c.cust_id, COUNT(*) num_accounts
from customer c LEFT JOIN
account a on a.account_id = c.cust_id
GROUP BY c.cust_id
ORDER BY num_accounts;
```

?

I was coming from an assumption that *num_accounts* is a column generated by aggregation and GROUP BY should be used.

thanks

Comment: ...due to MySQL error: Can't group on 'num_accounts'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order this SQL is processed in is not the same order it is written. Joins first, Where, groups, select, then order by last. What this means is that num_accounts does not exist in the group by stage. You can use this instead

```
GROUP BY c.cust_id, COUNT(*)
```